# Using fetch to log/output json values

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch values from JSON, see below. I need the values for the very last "year", "month", "day", "cycle", "trend" in the object

```
{"co2":[{"year":"2012","month":"1","day":"1","cycle":"392.92","trend":"391.50"},
...
,{"year":"2022","month":"2","day":"20","cycle":"418.63","trend":"416.80"}]}
```

I've tried the following script, but it logs [object Object]. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```js
    async function loadnums() {
        const response = await fetch('https://global-warming.org/api/co2-api');
        const nums = await response.json();
        console.log(nums); 
    }
    loadnums();
```

Comment: Hm, if you run the very code snippet that you posted, you see it logs an object.  Are you perhaps using some software (like Internet Explorer - although I don't think it even supports `fetch`) that coerces data passed to `console.log` to a string? Or did you maybe originally have something other than `console.log` here, such as a custom logging function or `alert`? Please explain where you saw `[object Object]` exactly (maybe add a screenshot). See [screenshot in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Qrp2.png) where it looks all fine.

Comment: try `JSON.stringify`. Becuase chrome console works differently than any other place. In chrome console it will show the internal structure of the object upon loggin. What you can do is wrap any object as `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))`